# Hook to get the page template that is in use on the admin page edit screen?

Tags: templates

I would like to find out which page template is in use as I only want to enqueue some javascript if the page is using a certain template. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for [`is_page_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) ?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is for front end or back end, so I'm going to handle both.

### BACK END

You can make use of `get_current_screen()` or the `$pagenow` global. Here are two examples which you can add in a plugin or in your `functions.php` to check the relevant info on an admin page

```
add_action( 'current_screen', function ( $current_screen )
{
    ?><pre><?php var_dump($current_screen); ?></pre><?php   

});
```

and

```
add_action( 'admin_head', function ()
{
    global $pagenow;

    ?><pre><?php var_dump($pagenow); ?></pre><?php  

});
```

Once you have the name of the specific admin page, you can do the following

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', function ( $hook ) 
{
    if ( 'some-page.php' === $hook ) {
        // Add your scripts
    }
});
```

### FRONT END

As birgire pointed out, if you need to know this on front end, you can simply test this with `is_page_template( 'some-template.php' )`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function ()
{
    if ( is_page_template( 'some-template.php' ) ) {
        // Enqueue your script
    }
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Just wanted to add that the admin_enqueue_scripts hook receives a parameter of $hook - which holds the name data as the $pagenow global I believe.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in the end:

```
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $pagetemplate = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
        if ( !empty( $pagetemplate ) ) {
        if ( $pagetemplate == 'page-landing_child.php' ) {

           //do something
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: `is_page_template()` does all of that for you, check my answer

Comment: Why!? Check out @PieterGoosen's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was fumbling with this one, but then i remembered we have access to the post-id via a get-param in wp-admin

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_admin_head');
function my_admin_head() {
    if ( ! empty( $_GET['post'] ) ) {
        $post_id = sanitize_key( $_GET['post'] );
        $template_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', true );
        echo $template_name; exit;
    }
}
```